# Unable to do `npm start`

Tags: javascript, npm

I did an `npx create-react-app` then I did an `npm start` to see if it worked, and when I did it, it gave me this error [image: npm start error] I don't really know why it is giving me this error, but I tried everything that it said, yet it keeps giving the error.

Comment: Please don't use screenshots to share code or errors: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove the `node_modules` folder inside your home folder, the one at C:\Users\Simone\node_modules. Also, double-check that you don't have a package.json or package-lock.json files in your home folder.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like the error is related to a version conflict for that dependency. You could uninstall your version of Webpack with `npm uninstall webpack`, add the below dependency to your package.json file, then run `npm i` to get up-to-date.

`"webpack": "4.44.2"`